# Database Diagram Representation

Tags: c#, database, diagram

This is my first post here, feel great with this community.

I'm new in .NET using C# actually. I have a task to build a desktop application that analyzes sql server databases. I use Sql Server 2008.

In my application, I need to provide a facility to show/represent database diagram (like database diagram representation in Sql Server 2008).

I wonder if there are some library/components for the application's requirement?

Comment: did you search for the libraries then?

Comment: i've search for it, and i still can't found it, yet.
so i asked here for solution

Comment: You said you searched already, but did you use [this query](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+diagramming+library)? This gives plenty of results, just like [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926551/choosing-a-diagramming-library-for-net).