# What to use when creating a schedule diagram

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a schedule diagram in c# (Windows Forms). It's like this:

> M  T W TH F
>
> 7:30-8:30     8:30-9:30
>
> 10:30-11:30

What I need is like a table that I can fill up the taken schedule with a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can benefit from using DataGrid control ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Check this also : [choosing a diagramming library for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926551/choosing-a-diagramming-library-for-net)